# Aptana Studio 3 Javascript intellisense capitalizing the F in "function"

Tags: aptana

By default apatana is using 'Function' inside javascript instead of 'function' which causes javascript errors.

Is there a way to replace 'Function' with 'function' on the auto-complete/int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be an issued fixed in the upcoming 3.0.4 release: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1925.  For the moment you could update to the nightly build via the instruction here: http://aptana.com/r/apupdate.